# Substitute wrong dates with more than two forward slashes for NA (in R)

Tags: r, date, formatting, substitution

I would like to get rid off some dates in a column that are as follow (there are more than 40.000 records and I cannot go one by one):

```
d <- c("16/19/07/1953",
"16/19/08/1953",
"16/21/7/1/59",
"16/21/vii/1967")
```

I would like just to substitute these dates that have three forward slashes or more in some cases by NA. Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this work? `is.na(d) <- nchar(d) - nchar(gsub("/", "", d, fixed = TRUE)) > 2`

Comment: If these are in a column of other dates, if you convert the entire column to `Date`-class, all strings that are non-compliant with the format will naturally become `NA`. For instance, I'm inferring that the "real" underlying structure is `%d/%m/%Y`, in which case `as.Date(d, format = "%d/%m/%Y")` will convert correct dates to `Date` and incorrect (such as these) to `NA`.

Comment: Both answers work perfectly. Thanks to both! Ekoam approach fix specifically what I need and r2evans answer works fine but because I still need to work on some typos and errors on the dates I'm going to use the first approach (in order to don't lose many dates in this cleaning stage).